# Why do I get null reference error in IE but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, checkbox

due to layout reasons I needed to write a routine that checks if at least one checkbox is checked on a specific form (in a typo3 form where things have to be checked on 3 sites that can be switched by next button, which is a submit button - on every site there has to be checked at least one parameter). The routine also handles diff. languages so it can be translated...

But somehow IE (I tried with IE11) throws a null reference error when this line is reached (but in Firefox it works perfectly):

```
if (elems[i].children[0].control['checked'] === true
```

here is the whole routine:

```
     if(document.getElementById("pollFR") != null &&  document.getElementById("pollFR") != '' ){
        document.getElementById("pollFR").addEventListener("submit", submitCheckboxHandler);
        language = "FR"
    }

//some more identical if-statements, because there is a form for every //language e.g. pollEN, etc.

    function submitCheckboxHandler(ev) {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('form-check');
        var elemCounter = 0;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            if (elems[i].children[0].control['checked'] === true)
                elemCounter++;
        };
        if (elemCounter === 0) {
            switch(language){
                case "EN":
                    alert("Please choose at least one parameter!");
                    break;
                case "FR":
                    alert("...french...");
                default:
                    alert("...german...");
            }
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why this happens ?

Thanks !

EDIT:
as it was asked for, the generated HTML looks like this (snippet):

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div id="c332">
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="poll" [...] />
    </div>
    <h2>Gap-analysis</h2>

    <input autocomplete="off" aria-hidden="true" id="poll-v3Bmj4bQKnD6hScEI" [...] name="tx_form_formframework[poll][v3Bmj4bQKnD6hScEI]" />

    <fieldset id="poll-fieldset-1" class="form-group">

      <legend>text:</legend>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-1 col-lg-4">

          <div class="form-group">

            <label class="control-label" for="poll-multicheckbox-1">text</label>

            <div class="input checkbox">
              <div id="poll-multicheckbox-1" class="inputs-list">

                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="poll-multicheckbox-1-0">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="tx_form_formframework[poll][multicheckbox-1]" value="" /><input id="poll-multicheckbox-1-0" type="checkbox" name="tx_form_formframework[poll][multicheckbox-1][]" value="term" />
                                        <span>term</span>
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
[......]
            <div class="actions">

<nav class="form-navigation">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <span class="next">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="tx_form_formframework[poll][__currentPage]" value="1">Weiter</button>
                    </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
            </div>
        </form>


<!-- end snippet -->
```

every "poll" will become like "pollEN" on language switch...

Comment: Check the browser support for the plugin (typo 3?)

Comment: Why not `if (elems[i].children[0].control.checked)`

Comment: @mplungjan Will that make a difference? Curious.

Comment: Perhaps not. It just looked wrong. But a [mcve] would be great

Comment: @mplungjan  It would be if snippets where working, currently 503, :(  Is there a report problem for this on SO?.

Comment: `.children[0]`, Are we sure all elements have some children?

Comment: @Keith Editing or running? Adding HTML would be helpful in itself

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You cannot have a <div><form></div> and where are the previous/next buttons?

Comment: yeah that´s because the generated HTML is like 400lines and I simply forgot to search then end tag at the bottom. I will update it now.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I suggest you could add the same class for the checkbox control, then, based on the class to find the checkbox and check whether the check box is checked or not. Please refer to the following code:

```
<input id="Checkbox1" class="check_language" type="checkbox" value="Item A" /> Item A <br />
<input id="Checkbox1" class="check_language" type="checkbox" value="Item B" /> Item B <br />
<input id="Checkbox1" class="check_language" type="checkbox" value="Item C" /> Item C <br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_submit" type="submit" name="tx_form_formframework[poll][__currentPage]" value="1">Weiter</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("btn_submit").addEventListener("click", submitCheckboxHandler);
    function submitCheckboxHandler(event) {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("check_language")
        var elemCounter = 0;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            if (elems[i].checked === true)
                elemCounter++;
        };
        if (elemCounter === 0) {
            //switch (language) {
            //    case "EN":
            //        alert("Please choose at least one parameter!");
            //        break;
            //    case "FR":
            //        alert("...french...");
            //    default:
            //        alert("...german...");
            //}
            alert("Please choose at least one parameter!");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            alert("Already selected " + elemCounter + " item");
        }
    };
</script>
```